# Is there a way to deploy/update Spring Batch Jobs seperately?

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, spring-batch

We're running a Spring Batch Web-Application for Importing CSV Files into a Database. This Web-Application is currently evolving and is constantly extended by new jobs.

the current update procedure looks like this:
1. Write new Code
2. Build a war file
3. Deploy the newly build war file and replace the whole Web Application on the Tomcat Webserver

This might bring us into trouble, when the running system is currently importing / writing Files to the Database.

I wanted to know if there is a smart way to maybe upgrade the spring batch jobs seperately ?

I already thought about splitting the Project into many different Web-Applications but this might be a lot of overhead with all the libraries bundled into the war file(s).

Are there any best practices for building that sort of Application ?

Thanks for your Help !

Comment: I think you should use transactions to make sure your data are consistence.

Comment: That might prevent us form any data loss, we could also wait for the jobs to finish before we upgrade the Application. We are already using transaction based Jobs, but we're looking for a better way to deploy / upgrade the jobs or the Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This packaging model is known to cause a lot of issues like the one you are facing. I recommend to package your jobs as separate jars and make your application launch those jobs in separate processes. With this model, you can deploy/upgrade jobs without impacting the web application used to launch them.

For the record, Spring Batch Admin suffered from this packaging model (as described [here](https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-batch-admin/blob/master/MIGRATION.md)) and the recommended replacement is [Spring Cloud Data Flow](https://dataflow.spring.io) (which uses the model I described previously)

Comment: You sir deserve a medal ! Thank you once again !
I'll have a look at SCDF eventhough it looks quite complicated at the first look.